# How is it possible for me to pass margins into a component in React with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass some CSS attributes to a component that I'm using because I need it to just get it displayed with different margins in a specific space, so that's why I'm just trying to pass the margins directly.

Does someone has any idea on how can I do it?

I've already tried to do something like `<Loader style={nameOfStyle} />` but typescript is not letting me to do this.

What's the best way to pass the props to it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Custom components will only take "style" at a type level if its in their props, if you have control over the "Loader" component the fix is simple just do this...

```
interface IProps {
    style?: CSSProperties
}

export const Loader = (props: IProps) => {
    return (
        <div style={props.style}>LOADER</div>
    )
}
```

Let me know if this helps, if it don't have control over "Loader" let me know also

EDIT:

Typescript isn't letting you do this because you need to tell typescript that "Loader" the component takes styles. By the look at the small amount of original code you have some object or string "nameOfStyle" you're trying to pass to Loader but typescript is preventing you.

To fix this go into Loader component, find where you defined the props structure and add this.

```
style?: CSSProperties
```

Once you have done that... this code should succeed

```
<Loader style={{margin: "2px"}}/>
```

However.... the margin will still not be applied until inside the "Loader" component you apply the margin from props to the correct element.

Comment: The problem is that I cant use `style`, take a look at this. `Type '{ style: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.`

Comment: Correct because you haven't told Loader that it can take "style" as a property.

Comment: Typescript is not letting you do it because you haven't told typescript that Loader can take "style" as a prop, its protecting you. You need to tell typescript Loader can take "style" as a prop and then it will be happy

Comment: Okay, now how can I actually add the margins I actually need to add?

Comment: Right now I have it like this `<Loader style={props.style}/>` then how can I pass the margins I need it to have?

Comment: Sure, I'll wait for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way easier solution to this:

First, we create a new component:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  margin: 25px;
`;
```

Then we wrap the element we want to be affected by the margins inside it:

```
<Container>
    <Loader/>
</Container>
```

That worked!